# bach update on dbeaver

Tags: sql, dbeaver

I need to update a database with like this:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET columnb='01001'
WHERE columnb IN ('lraXh7QFkB2','fhh1ZmczNeXA', 'H1M1aL1kL','5-RNsXxrE8DeQ2' )
```

when I run it on the query editor it works fine, the same is I save the query on a .sql file and import it to execute.

But if the file has several statemes like:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET columnb='01001'
WHERE columnb IN ('lraXh7QFkB2','fhh1ZmczNeXA', 'H1M1aL1kL','5-RNsXxrE8DeQ2' )
UPDATE my_table
SET columnb='021001'
WHERE columnb IN ('lraXh7QFkB2','fhh1ZmczNeXA', 'H1M1aL1kL','5-RNsXxrE8DeQ2' )
UPDATE my_table
SET columnb='010031'
WHERE columnb IN ('lraXh7QFkB2','fhh1ZmczNeXA', 'H1M1aL1kL','5-RNsXxrE8DeQ2' )
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
```

that occurs at line four just after updating for the first case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have semicolons at the end of each update statement

```
UPDATE my_table
SET columnb='01001'
WHERE columnb IN ('lraXh7QFkB2','fhh1ZmczNeXA', 'H1M1aL1kL','5-RNsXxrE8DeQ2' );
UPDATE my_table
SET columnb='021001'
WHERE columnb IN ('lraXh7QFkB2','fhh1ZmczNeXA', 'H1M1aL1kL','5-RNsXxrE8DeQ2' );
UPDATE my_table
SET columnb='010031'
WHERE columnb IN ('lraXh7QFkB2','fhh1ZmczNeXA', 'H1M1aL1kL','5-RNsXxrE8DeQ2' );
```